# Location to the volume control and connect to a wifi network in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have added 'some' restrictions to an account on my computer, however, as I disabled the system tray, the user can't access the volume control or connect to a wifi network.

So, can somebody please give me the location to the volume control program, and connect to a network program? I will then add shortcuts to the start-menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Volume Control**
The volume mixer application is `SndVol32.exe` in 32-bit Windows and `SndVol.exe` in 64-bit Windows. It is located in C:\WINDOWS\System32 (in both 32- and 64-bit) and C:\WINDOWS\SysWow64 in 64-bit Windows.

**Connect to a Network**
In Windows 7 you can access the Network and Sharing center with the command `control /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter`. Here you can click Connect to a network. This may not be the approach you are looking for, but I have yet to find another way.

**Windows Mobility Center**
If this is a portable computer, you can also access both of these controls (and others) with [Windows Mobility Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/Using-Windows-Mobility-Center). It's in Control Panel or you can access it with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Supposedly [this article describes how to enable Windows Mobility Center for computers that are not laptops](http://www.dubuque.k12.ia.us/it/mobilitycenter/). It involves a registry change that I have not tested.

Comment: Thanks! I have provided a start menu shortcut to the mobility center, as I have also diasabled the control.exe program, and win button shortcuts.